# loop updating the entire column of the 2D array in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm running the following code with Ruby version `2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux]`:

```rb
table = Array.new(3, Array.new(3, 0))
for i in 1..2
  table[i][0] = i
end
p table
```

I expect this to print:

```rb
[
 [0, 0, 0],
 [1, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0]
]
```

Instead I'm somehow getting:

```rb
[
 [2, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0],
 [2, 0, 0]
]
```

I can reproduce this with other loops. Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Any idea what's going on here?

Your 3 inner arrays are actually all the same object. (See [Common gotchas](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Array.html#method-c-new-label-Common+gotchas))

To get an array of 3 *different* arrays, you have to pass a block to `Array.new`:

```
table = Array.new(3) { Array.new(3, 0) }
```

The inner array `Array.new(3, 0)` doesn't need the block form because `0` is immutable.